# Firestore firebase result success without items (sometimes)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore Firebase without Persistence enabled.
I am making a Query, exact same query. 
I always getting success result, sometimes with items and sometimes without.

**Thats how i create the task:**

```
          Task<QuerySnapshot> retrieveTask = mFireBaseFireStore.collection(collectionPath)
                .limit(BATCH_SIZE)
                .orderBy(Name.NAME_OBJECT_INDEX_KEY)
                .startAt(startIndex)
                .get();
```

**Thats how i am listening:**

```
            retrieveTask.addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {

                ///

            emitter.onSuccess(res);
        }).addOnFailureListener(emitter::onError);
```

I think i get no results when it's a poor connection, but connectivity status
is always connected even during no results.
its only sometimes.

i was thinking maybe firebase cannot get results from internet and returning from the "empty cache" but its not true - i disabled the cache.

How can i know that there is no result not because there is no data?

i am using firebase-core version: 17.0.0
and firebase-firestore version: 20.1.0.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be certain there are no documents matching a query when:

- [QuerySnapshot.empty()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot.html#isEmpty()) returns true
- [QuerySnapshot.getMetadata().isFromCache()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SnapshotMetadata.html#isFromCache()) return false